LLM Azure Openai - Unable to connect to PostgreSQL DB
I am using LLM in Azure OpenAI and trying to connect to my local instance of PostgreSQL.
Getting error.
The code and error are paste here.
Help is much appreciated.

#!pip install langchain psycopg2
#!pip install --upgrade langchain-experimental
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase, SQLDatabaseChain

host = "localhost"
port = 5433  
database = "dvdrental"
user = "postgres"
password = "xxxxxxx"

db_conn = SQLDatabase(host, port, database, user, password)

db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain(db_conn)`



ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-52-eb9cde349665\> in \<cell line: 4\>()
2 #!pip install --upgrade langchain-experimental
3 from langchain.llms import OpenAI
\----\> 4 from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase, SQLDatabaseChain
5
6 #host=localhost port=5433 dbname=dvdrental user=postgres password=xxxxxxx connect_timeout=10 sslmode=prefer

ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLDatabaseChain' from 'langchain.sql_database' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain


For sql database chain you need to use create_sql_query_chain from langchain package.
Below is the sample code.
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import create_sql_query_chain
from langchain_community.utilities import SQLDatabase

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///Chinook.db")
llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0)
chain = create_sql_query_chain(llm, db)
response = chain.invoke({"question": "How many employees are there"})

Refer this for more about chains.

Thank you Jayashanar.  I am going through the docs.  Will update this thread soon.
